# An equation that is undefined at every value except one (plotting a single point)

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions

Suppose I wanted to plot an equation that would only place a single point at a specific (x,y) value, and nothing anywhere else, that is, the equation, y=g(x), would be undefined for all other x values except the x from that one (x,y) point. What might that look like?

I toyed around with dividing by zero in the equation (to make all x-values undefined and therefor not plotted), but I wasn’t sure how to not divide by zero IFF x is the x-value I want plotted. I know Kronecker Delta function could be used here but afaik it only has a definition as a piecewise function and obviously that defeats the entire purpose of what I’m trying to do. I suspect the answer will involve limits. Any ideas?

I also have an idea of plotting the equation for a circle with its center at the (x,y) point and the radius approaching zero, but I don’t know enough about limits to know if that will suffice?

Comment: By definition, functions are defined on every value of their domains so you would have to make your domain a one point set.

Comment: @john douma is an equation like $y=3/x$ not a function even though it has no value at x=0?

Comment: Yes but its domain does not include $0$.

Comment: @john douma thanks, I have no formal training in math so I often get terminology wrong. Editing question now to reflect what I’m really asking

Comment: You could still use the Kronecker delta in a division if you really want to make this thing undefined almost everywhere.

Comment: @Sean Roberson, does it have a non-piecewise definition?

Comment: What do you mean non-piecewise? I can cheat and instead use an Iverson bracket. Otherwise, you'll be using a very inconvenient uncountable infinite product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of real functions
$$f(x) =  \sqrt x + \sqrt{-x}$$

has a graph consisting of only the point $(0,0)$

Comment: This is really interesting because it seems to still be continuous, right? Just everything else is hidden in the complex plane. I like this answer best because it behaves most like a real function and can be manipulated (translated) to any point I desire. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can just write $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=0$.  This equation has only the point $(x_0,y_0)$ as solution.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking into doing with my circle attempt I had referenced. For some reason I was under the impression it would have to be the limit as the radius approaches zero, hadn't realized it could work directly at zero, but upon seeing it written out this is obvious, I was just thinking visually in my head, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The graph of the function f = {(x,y)} is a single point.
The constant function f:{0} -> {1}, x -> 1, for example.

You could conjure up a meaningless monster like
f(x) = x/0 if x /= 0;  f(0) = 0/0 = 1 or whatever.

I don't see any slick answer for a dubious problem.
Use the set theory definition of function
instead of a naive calculus notion.